# Are photon wavelength and energy indirect measurements of one-way speed of light?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, speed-of-light

First, measure the wavelength ($\lambda$) of an EM wave with, say, a chocolate bar in a microwave oven.

Then, measure its average photon energy and get the wave frequency ($\nu=\frac{E}{h}$).

Now you have the one-way speed of light ($c=\lambda\nu$)...

What is wrong here?

Comment: Just some friendly advice... the one-way speed of light business is a rabbit hole that doesn't lead anywhere productive. It's purely a convention, and there is a clear best choice of convention that makes both the math and physics clear: that the speed of light is the same "forward" and "backward". If you don't make this choice, all you are doing is making it harder to understand what is going on, but the results you will compute for any physical observable are the same as the convention with the speed of light the same.

Comment: Does $E=h\nu$ hold when the speed of light is anisotropic? (think about the whole process of quantizing the EM field) . I myself don't know, but here is a place where maybe you could see a difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you assume that light satisfies a wave equation then it is true that knowing the wavelength and frequency allows you to determine the velocity.

But, assuming light satisfies a wave equation already presumes the "one-way speed of light" is constant in all directions. That is, isotropic propagation already follows from assuming you have a wave equation. So posing the question in this way is [begging the question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question).

The interesting result of this question and line of inquiry is the realization that for the one-way speed of light to differ in different directions would require the equations governing light (the Maxwell equations) to be different than the ones we usually assume.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Do you know of any effort to formulate classical electromagnetism under such anisotropy?

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft no, I haven't really dived too deep into one-way speed of light stuff. I'd start by googling stuff like anisotropic wave equations. Such physics occurs in anistoropic crystals such a birefringent crystals. That said, that gives different velocities for travelling up/down compared to left/right. I don't think I know of an equation that describes a wave travelling with a different velocity left versus right.

Answer (score -2):

If the classical electromagnetic wave has a unique  wavelength, it will also have a unique frequency, so no "average photon energy",it will be unique $E=hν$. Photon energies are measured by atomic transitions, the photon is absorbed by the atom and the electron goes to a higher orbital.

Your reasoning is circular. The three, $ν$, $λ$ and c  are interconnected . If the de-excitation of the atom  did not give the same wavelength as the incoming one, and using the   $νλ$ does not give a unique constant  c , we would not have the consistent data we have up to now on spectroscopy etc.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Can this consistency in spectroscopic data be used as empirical evidence for light-speed isotropy?

Comment: It can be used to support the constancy of c, but I do not see how it can be used for the one way argument.